# JQuery Mobile connection to database

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile. I have created a simple front end asking the user to login and now I want to connect to a mssql 2008 db to check the users credentials. how can I do it. I want to use Java technology as my backend code. your help will be appreciated.

Comment: why is this question given a -ve point...what is the reason!! probably not got an answer for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect jQuery mobile with DB. Just use JAVA as you would without jQuery mobile.

Comment: are you sure,because I have seen php and .net technology using jquery mobile as frond end and connecting to database